Find multiplicity of $2$ in $x^{2^{2024}} - y^{2^{2024}}$
Find multiplicity of 2 in $x^{2^{2024}} - y^{2^{2024}}$  if $x, y$ are odd and $ x-y \equiv 2 \pmod{8}$
Attempt:
$$\phi(2^n) = 2^{n-1}$$
By Euler's Theorem,
$$x^{2^{2024}} - y^{2^{2024}} \equiv 1 - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{2025}}$$
Thus, I answered $2025$.
However, the answer listed ( solution not given ) was $2026$. How can you find an extra power of $2$ that divides the number? I'm not able to use the fact that $ x-y \equiv 2 \pmod{8}$.

What does find the multiplicity of $2$ mean here?

highest power of $p$ that divides a number is its multiplicity

FYI, see Lifting-the-exponent lemma, with it indicating that $\nu_2(x^{2^{2024}}-y^{2^{2024}})$ is not uniquely determined by just the provided information. Note this lemma uses $x-y\equiv 2\pmod{8}$ for the value of $\nu_2(x-y)$, but $\nu_2(x+y)$ can be any value of $2$ or higher, so the minimum value is $2026$, with there being no maximum value. For example, if $x=2^m+1$ and $y=2^m-1$ for any $m \ge 1$, then $\nu_2(x+y)=m+1$, which leads to $\nu_2(x^{2^{2024}}-y^{2^{2024}})=2025+m$.

Note I found the duplicates using an Approach0 search. There are also other questions that are basically duplicates, such as divisible problem.
